# Jest mock sendgrid send email

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sendgrid

I use sendGrid email in my nodejs app

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/master/packages/mail

And basically, when user signs up, I will send a welcome email

But when I write test for user sign up, I want to mock sendgrid send function. How can I do it with jest. Or any suggestion on how can I test the signup api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sendgrid's [sandbox mode](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sandbox-mode/) to avoid emails actually being sent

Comment: The second link is broken. That's why we always recommend you at least add a snippet of your reference

Answer (score 6):

For the javascript/node version of sendgrid we added the following:

```
mail_settings: {
      sandbox_mode: {
          enable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test',
      },
  }
```

so it looked like this in context:

```
const msg =  {
      to: email,
      from: EMAIL_FROM,
      subject,
      replyTo: REPLY_TO,
      dynamicTemplateData,
      templateId,
      mail_settings: {
          sandbox_mode: {
              enable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test',
          },
      }
  };
  sgMail.send(msg)
```

This solution came from [coinhndp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8737224/coinhndp) along with additional info on syntax from [github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/612). It works because when we run `npm test` the scripts set our environment to `'test'`, which then sets `sandbox_mode { enable: true }`.

To get it working with jest we have a `jestSetup.js` file:

```
jest.setTimeout(15000);

jest.mock('@sendgrid/mail');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const defaultMailOptions = { response: 'Okay' };

beforeAll(() => {
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
});

beforeEach(() => {
  global.mockMailer = (options=defaultMailOptions) => {
    return sgMail.sendMultiple.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(options));
  };
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

Which allows us to add `beforeEach(() => mockMailer());` to our tests. It's worth noting that we only use sendMultiple() for sending emails with sendgrid, you may be using a different function in your application.

Comment: Have you set the API key? If you use dotenv, remember to set it for testing env too

Comment: @coinhndp Yes, the API key is set and remains the same for both testing and dev, and the NODE_ENV gets set with scripts. I'm not sure if the decisive difference was not using camelCase or if it was changing `enabled` to `enable`.

Comment: @coinhndp Either it silently would not engage sandbox mode so emails would get sent, or it would give a "Bad Request" response and no emails would get sent either from test or from production. A coworker today did write a solution using `jest.mock()`, I'll update the answer with what she wrote.

Comment: Great. We could mock the sendEmail also